# How do you make pictures blink alternatively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have two pictures that I want them to blink alternatively. I used CSS and javascript to blink individual picture but failed to make the second picture start to show up at the offset of the first picture. Is there any way to control the timing?

tried: first picture used the following and the second one reversed the opacity.

```
.blinking{
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 1s infinite;    
    animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink{

    100%{ opacity:1;}
    0%{opacity:0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes blink{

    100%{ opacity:1;}
    0%{opacity:0;}

}

@keyframes blink{

    100%{ opacity:1;}
    0%{opacity:0;}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `animation-delay`

```css
.blinking {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

.delay {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }      
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blinking">image 1</div>
<div class="blinking delay">image 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the animation delay property. You may be able to time the delay to start when the fist image is mid-blink.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

Comment: The delay property doesn't help. After the delay the pictures blink at the same time